# error when trying to install ros hydro on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ros, ros-hydro, ubuntu-precise, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to install ROS on ubuntu 12.04 to use it with both gazebo and morse.

I first installed ROS fuerte, but the setup.* files were not created in /opt/ros/fuerte. So I removed ROS fuerte and tried to install ROS hydro. when typing sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-desktop-full an error occurred:

> user@user-SATELLITE-L750:~$ sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-desktop-full
> [sudo] password for user:
> Reading package lists... Done
> Building dependency tree
> Reading state information... Done
> Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
> requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
> distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
> or been moved out of Incoming.
> The following information may help to resolve the situation:
> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
> ros-hydro-desktop-full : Depends: ros-hydro-simulators but it is not going to be installed
> E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

How can I resolve this ?

thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/194433/error-when-trying-to-install-ros-hydro-on-ubuntu-12.04/) by [djou](https://answers.ros.org/users/20411/djou/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2014-10-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I did what you said but it does not work, always the same error for ROS Hydro:/

After that I reinstalled ROS fuerte and setup.* where finally created.

Thank you :)

---

Originally posted by [djou](https://answers.ros.org/users/20411/djou/) with karma: 16 on 2014-10-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi djou

please try `sudo apt-get upgrade` which will try to solve your problems. 
*OR* 
Try it all again by first cleaning and reinstalling later:

```
sudo apt-get remove ros-hydro-desktop-full
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoclean

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-desktop-full
```

---

Originally posted by [ct2034](https://answers.ros.org/users/12141/ct2034/) with karma: 862 on 2014-10-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2